# Create a file to import all modules that are contained within said file

Tags: python, import, module

Is there a way I can import a list of modules that are contained within a single file just by using one statement without building some sort of method?

E.g.

large_import_file.py

```
import x,y,z
```

main.py

```
import large_import_file

x.do_this()
y.do_this()
z.do_this()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring in all of methods and imports for large_import_file to the current file's namespace, you'd just do.

```
from large_import_file import *
```

As silent mentioned in his answer this is covered in 
[Python more on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)